# Video not working in Virtualbox on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, video

I have installed **Windows 7 32-bit IE11 OVA** in Virtualbox from Linux Mint.

I have installed `LonelyScreen` to airplay my iOS 9 device. The LonelyScreen appears in the AirPlay in my iPhone and I am able to connect to it, but I only see a blank screen. The video is not playing. I also tried playing videos from a Youtube app, the audio is being played but not video. I have also set acceleration to `HyperV` and also tried with **Legacy**

I have set the video memory to **128 MB** or so (of 256 MB total) and also **Enabled 2D acceleration and 3D acceleration**

I have connected the Virtualbox to `wlan0` (here, it is `wlp6s0` for me) instead of NAT through which iPhone is able to detect the AirPlay but it is not streaming video but only audio.

I have also disabled Firewall in both Linux OS and Windows but still it didn't work.

P.S: I also tried installing X-Mirage, audio worked but not video or mirroring. But, I am able to play videos in my Windows 7 (in Virtualbox) from my Local disk and also from Youtube in Windows 7. But the video is not working while airplay.